# Any ideas how can I add header to this function?

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, token

Any ideas how can I add header to the function shown below? I created login service and I get in response status 200. However when I then try to send GET request I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden).`

```
  func() {
    return this.http.get('/data', )
        .map(response => response.json())
        .subscribe(response2 => this.response2 = response2);
}
```

my GET:

```
get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.get(appConfig.apiUrl + url, this.addJwt(options)).catch(this.handleError);
}

 private addJwt(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
        // ensure request options and headers are not null
        options = options || new RequestOptions();
        options.headers = options.headers || new Headers();

        // add authorization header with jwt token
        let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
            options.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + currentUser.token);
        }

        return options;
    }
```

**SOLUTION**
The problem was that the backend was expecting Token to send in the form `Token 132083128901302` however I was sending `Bearer 132083128901302`. After changing Bearer to Token everything works properly.

Comment: looks like you are already adding headers at the point where you have the comment `// add authorization header with jwt token`.  What header do you think is missing?

Comment: Just FYI, the `.subscribe()` is definitely wrong. `.catch(this.handleError);` is even worse and comes directly from the Angular official guide (it needs to be `.catch(e => this.handleError(e));`). The moral being that the Angular official guide is completely terrible
. Shame on you, Ward Bell.

Comment: Even with the change from `.subscribe()` to `.subscribe(response2 => this.response2 = response2);`, the code is still wrong because you do not want to return the subscription from the service call in `LoginService`, just the `Observable`. Unless you are using `Http` directly in a component which is bad

Comment: I created this function only for tests to check if the header is well added

Answer (score 0):

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwt });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.get('http://test.dev/get/user', options).map(res => res.json());
```

I would highly suggest you to use interceptors through HttpClient Module. It is easy to implement, less code in the app, easier to manage.

Comment: But this code is used only once. After login header is added automatically and there is no difference between you solution and mine, isn't it?

Comment: No it isn't that different at all. That is why I said use Interceptors. I gave you the code just as a solution.
I'll link a tutorial for you, or you can search by yourself as there are plenty of tutorials on how to implement Angular Interceptors.
Interceptors are like a middleware, for every request they add the headers automatically and then process the request. So you will have to add the headers only in one place.
https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8